# EsLint airbnb-base import/no-unresolved

Tags: vue.js, eslint, eslint-config-airbnb

I have a created a project using Vue-cli and I decided to add a lint configuration by default.
I'm not sure why, when i run the lint command, i get the following:

> error: Unable to resolve path to module '@/components/HelloWorld.vue' (import/no-unresolved) at src/views/Home.vue:10:24:

Here is my Home view:

```
<template>
  <div class="home">
    <HelloWorld></HelloWorld>
    Home
  </div>
</template>

<script>
// @ is an alias to /src
import HelloWorld from "@/components/HelloWorld.vue";

export default {
  name: "home",
  components: {
    HelloWorld,
  },
};
</script>
```

here is my  HelloWorld component

```
<template>
  <div>Dea Formazione - registrazione</div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "HelloWorld",
};
</script>

<!-- Add "scoped" attribute to limit CSS to this component only -->
<style scoped lang="scss"></style>
```

here is my eslint config:

```
{
  "env": {
    "node": true,
    "browser": true,
    "es6": true
  },
  "extends": ["airbnb-base", "plugin:vue/essential", "@vue/prettier"],
  "globals": {
    "Atomics": "readonly",
    "SharedArrayBuffer": "readonly"
  },
  "parserOptions": {
    "extends": "standard"
  },
  "rules": {},
  "settings": {
    "import/resolver": {
      "node": {
        "paths": ["src"],
        "extensions": [".js", ".jsx", ".vue"]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Is there anything wrong?

Answer (score 5):

I posted a solution for the `alias` problem in my Medium article: https://medium.com/@agm1984/how-to-set-up-es-lint-for-airbnb-vue-js-and-vs-code-a5ef5ac671e8

It's basically this:

**Install**:

```
npm install --save-dev eslint-import-resolver-alias
```

**Laravel-mix (aka Webpack config)**

```
mix.webpackConfig({
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.js', '.vue'],
        alias: {
            '@': `${__dirname}/resources`,
            '~': path.join(__dirname, './resources/js'),
        },
    },
});
```

Note the resolve key there if you are using something ultra-wild like “just Webpack by itself and not Laravel Mix”; there will be a standard deviation of syntax.

**.eslintrc.json**

```
{
    "env": {},

    "rules: {},

    "settings": {
        "import/resolver": {
            "alias": {
                "map": [
                    ["@", "./resources"],
                    ["~", "./resources/js"]
                ],
                "extensions": [".js", ".vue"]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

source: https://github.com/benmosher/eslint-plugin-import/issues/496

Comment: The issue in OP's question is that his eslintrc config seems to show the old syntax. It changed in one of the newer versions of something.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this problem with installing the next library:

```
npm install eslint-import-resolver-webpack
```

And add the next param inside your settings in the eslintrc file, below the "node" one:

```
"webpack" : {
    "config": "path/to/setup/webpack.config.js"
}
```

Which will process your webpack.config.js file in order to know which configuration you are using in the project.

Comment: I tried this solution but it didn't work. I tried to check the path provided as config and I don't have that folder.

Comment: I thought you were working with a Laravel project. My bad! You need to replace what i gave you as the "config" value with the path to your `webpack.config.js` file